# Health Check failed - Atlassian's Localstack

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, localstack

Pretty much as the title <strike>says</strike> said.

I'm trying to run localstack, via docker on CentOS 7, having nothing but trouble.

Today's problem is `ERROR:localstack.services.kinesis.kinesis_starter:Kinesis health check failed: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: http://localhost.localdomain:4568/`

which apparently is cause for the entire thing to restart, and that is less than ideal when the s3 mock doesn't persist...

And rather than struggle through that I figured it would just be easier to not have kinesis run, at all, or even better; to only run the services that I'm attempting to use.

I assumed the `SERVICES` environment var might help, but it seems to only specify ports. If I exclude services from the provided list they run regardless...

Is there any way I can choose a subset of the services provided in localstack?

**EDIT**

So after some fiddling, reading, etc... 
managed to get things started via `localstack start --docker`

Previously user didn't have appropriate privilege, and running `sudo localstack start --docker` apparently ignores environment vars I have set.
But that's remedied now and I'm just starting S3 and SES services.

So now S3 runs into the same error;
`ERROR:localstack.services.s3.s3_starter:S3 health check failed: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: http://localhost.localdomain:4572/`
Even though I can make use of it myself, it's working fine, this check fails.

**MORE EDIT**

So I'm just not going to use LocalStack.
Not even sure where the issue lies, could be in boto or the config of my VM, but I have better things to do than track that down for little gain...

Might check in again in the future, see what's up then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SERVICES` environment variable.

For example, to start only S3 and DynamoDB:

```
SERVICES=s3,dynamodb localstack start
```

Or, to start LocalStack in a Docker container:

```
SERVICES=s3,dynamodb localstack start --docker
```

(Note: This assumes that you have installed LocalStack via `pip install localstack`)

Comment: I assumed that _was_ the case, and that's what I tried.
And as I wrote, all services run regardless.
However, if I run as root then all is okay...

Comment: Turns out it's all irrelevant anyway, S3 fails on health check also.
Which is again apparently cause to restart all services... Despite the fact that it's actually working fine and I'm using it as it decides to restart.

Can I disable the health check?